# cake_session 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I moved to a SQL cluster environment with Percona (3 master-master synchronous nodes, using galera load balancer), and converted all dbs to InnoDB. we now keep getting this in our CakePHP 1.3 application

> 2013-09-11 09:16:52 Sql_errors: Session error:  (1213: Deadlock found
>   when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction) -
>   File:/cake/libs/cake_session.php - Line:759
>
> 2013-09-11 09:16:52 Sql_errors: Session error:  (1213: Deadlock found
>   when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction) -
>   File:/cake/libs/cake_session.php - Line:759
>
> 2013-09-11 10:54:49 Sql_errors: Session error:  (1213: Deadlock found
>   when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction) -
>   File:/cake/libs/cake_session.php - Line:759
>
> 2013-09-11 11:36:36 Sql_errors: Session error:  (1213: Deadlock found
>   when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction) -

since it's part of the core of CakePHP I am a bit weary of making any modifications. I wonder if anyone has ever had this problem with CakePHP and what suggestions might be useful to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

For a thorough explanation of what's going on here, see [Percona XtraDB Cluster: Multi-node writing and Unexpected deadlocks](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/08/17/percona-xtradb-cluster-multi-node-writing-and-unexpected-deadlocks/).

TL;DR version:

> Dealing with this problem, quite simply, is the tradeoff to multi-node writing in a synchronous replication system with optimistic locking.
>
> What can you do to work with/around this problem?  Here are some ideas from simplest to most complex:
>
> - Only write to a single node in the cluster (at a time)
> - Update your application DB library to handle sudden deadlocks
> - Restructure your application/schema to avoid data hot-spots